# Mods for Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I'm trying to help my young son to download/install Mods for Minecraft - but it seems like an impossible task. I know nothing about Minecraft, but have tried to download many Mods from different sites - some seems to be downloaded and some don't.

However - when downloading the files I'm never asked where to store the files, I don't know where they need to be stored, and even if some have been stored in the folders where all the other Minecraft files are, nothing happens in Minecraft when starting the game. So - what to do and how? Step-by-step please - as you undertsand from the above I'm on deep water here...

1. How to download and where to store the files
2. Any action to "activate" the files in Minecraft?

A million thanks from me & my son:-)

Comment: Maybe the first question is off topic for this site.

Comment: Ok if so forget the fist one...

Comment: So what process worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain, mods can be the hardest things to actually get working no matter how many tutorial you watch. I found this amazingly easy thing called technic. What it is, is a ton of mod combined into one pack so it'll be like a whole new Minecraft, your son will love it! It's very simple too, download the technic launcher (link below) and login with you Minecraft account and there you go! You just click the modpack you want to play (which ever you son wants) and then wait the 1-2 minutes it takes to download (time varies depending on your internet speed but it doesn't take that long. If you have any problems just comment them below! Have fun!

Technic Launcher - http://www.technicpack.net/

Comment: Hi - really appreciate your time and help - I'm now downloading this and hopefully it will work - my son will be even more thankful:-)

Comment: No problem, forge and technic are completely different. I recommend using technic before forge because it's much simpler.

Comment: Hi - I downloaded technic, but not Clear how to proceed from there. Does he have to start Minecraft from technic each time now, or the normal way? hen starting Minecraft the normal way no mods are found so seems nothing has changed...

Comment: No just start up technic and select your modpack on the right it should say Launch or something of the sort (Varies on version)

Comment: Hi - I see all the modpacks listed on the left side, I can click tem and then I get an "install" on the right bottom side, i have downloaded 2 of them now but still nothing seems to happen in Minecraft when we stat the game the normal way - again thanks for Your assistance...:_)

Comment: It's my pleasure man, Now here what it should look like, look at the mod pack's name then go all the way to the right and down. Then you'll see the option to delete the pack or to play it. Click play and it'll launch.

Answer (score 1):

> *Note*: Mods are the files which modifies/overrides the original game files to change, remove, add a game mechanics or assets. Installing mods is fundamentally changing the way *Minecraft* was meant to be played. **So *Mojang* will not be able to help you in any way, and are not responsible for crashes, data loss, etc**.

1. Only download mods from these sites : [Minecraft Forum](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods), [Minecraft Curseforge](http://minecraft.curseforge.com/mc-mods), [Planet Minecraft](http://www.planetminecraft.com/resources/mods/) or the sites that author of the mod suggests.
2. Normally there is *How to install* section in the forum post, so just follow it. Some mods have automatic installer, so you don't have to mess around with anything. But some mods that are built on top of modding API such as ModLoader or Forge you have to put a `.jar` or `.zip` file to `.minecraft\mods\` folder(This case you have to have installed API on minecraft beforehand). There are many good tutorials on youtube.
3. = 2.

Some custom launchers such as [MultiMC](http://multimc.org/) or [Magic Launcher](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262884) helps managing mods.

Helpful article: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mods/Installing_mods (Might be outdated)

Comment: Hi - I tried this, now Minecraft shows "3 mods active" however still nothing seems to happen in the game, we see no mods and nothings eems to have changed?

Comment: @Kevin Forge is just API that makes modders to change the game more easily. All you have to do now is donwload and locate your actual mod files (`.zip` or `.jar` files) in `.minecraft\mods\ `.

Answer (score 0):

1. All the mods that you download will be located in your downloads folder. This can be easily accessible by selecting the start button in the bottom left hand corner of your screen and then searching "Downloads"
2. Mods need to be loaded on a Minecraft Version called Minecraft Forge. Forge is what holds your mods and unpacks them to be used through out the game. The Link to download Forge is below.
3. Once you have forge and the mods you want downloaded in the start button search feild type "%appdata%". This will bring you straight to the Minecraft folder. Select the .minecraft file folder to open it. Then under the "mods" folder click and drag your mods into it.

Now that doesn't solve everything.

The next thing you need to do is open up the versions folder. Make a new file called Forge and put the downloaded Forge into the newly created folder.

Now open up Minecraft. You should see under the dropdown list your file name "Forge". Click on that version and play the game. The mods should now be activated.

Here is the link to [download forge.](http://files.minecraftforge.net/) Now because most mods are still run on version 1.7.10 I would recommend you download that version of Forge. Each mod is different though so please check the mods beforehand.

Comment: Not all mods are for Forge, -1.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Most mods are run on Forge not ALL mods. Forge is the easiest for someone who doesn't know a lot about the program, i.e the asker.

Comment: Since they're asking about all mods, you might want to say that in the answer instead of a comment. It's easier, but what happens if they download Optifine and try to install using these instructions…